# Test scrolling in a react-window list with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-window

I am stuck here with a test where I want to verify that after scrolling through a list component, imported by **react-window**, different items are being rendered. The list is inside a table component that saves the scrolling position in React context, which is why I need to test the whole table component.

Unfortunately, the scrolling event seems to have no effect and the list still shows the same items.

The test looks something like this:

```
render(
  <SomeProvider>
    <Table />
  </SomeProvider>
)

describe('Table', () => {
  it('scrolls and renders different items', () => {
    const table = screen.getByTestId('table')

    expect(table.textContent?.includes('item_A')).toBeTruthy() // --> true
    expect(table.textContent?.includes('item_Z')).toBeFalsy() // --> true

    // getting the list which is a child component of table
    const list = table.children[0]

    fireEvent.scroll(list, {target: {scrollY: 100}})

    expect(table.textContent?.includes('item_A')).toBeFalsy() // --> false
    expect(table.textContent?.includes('item_Z')).toBeTruthy() // --> false
  })
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried scrolling the window instead of the table ? 
    `fireEvent.scroll(window, { target: { scrollY: 100 } });`

I'm not sure if your table container has an overflow or not.

Comment: [@David Kerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3951121/david-kerr) I did not, but it might be worth a try. In the end, the test became obsolete because we rewrote most tests with browser automation (Playwright). In a real browser environment, the issue did no longer occur.

Answer (score 1):

`react-testing-library` by default renders your components in a jsdom environment, not in a browser. Basically, it just generates the html markup, but doesn't know where components are positioned, what are their scroll offsets, etc.

See for example [this issue](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/671#issuecomment-629380220).

Possible solutions are :

- use Cypress
- or override whatever native attribute react-window is using to measure scroll offset in your container (hacky). For example, let's say react-window is using container.scrollHeight :

```js
// artificially setting container scroll height to 200
Object.defineProperty(containerRef, 'scrollHeight', { value: 200 })
```

Comment: what is it - containerRef ? because containerRef is not defined.

Comment: This is just an idea of what kind of thing needs to be done, containerRef would be typically a ref on the scrollable element (that could be window if the whole page scrolls). But if you want to implement this, you need to take time reading react-window source code to know what properties on what elements to mock like this. It's not an easy task. Otherwise there's no way around with react-testing-library.

Comment: I agree, using react-testing-library for such a task is a stupid idea. may be later I will give an answer how to use cypress

Answer (score 1):

I had a scenario where certain presentation aspects depended on the scroll position. To make tests clearer, I defined the following mocks in test setup:

**1. Mocks that ensure programmatic scrolls trigger the appropriate events:**

```
const scrollMock = (leftOrOptions, top) => {
  let left;
  if (typeof (leftOrOptions) === 'function') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    ({ top, left } = leftOrOptions);
  } else {
    left = leftOrOptions;
  }
  Object.assign(document.body, {
    scrollLeft: left,
    scrollTop: top,
  });
  Object.assign(window, {
    scrollX: left,
    scrollY: top,
    scrollLeft: left,
    scrollTop: top,
  }).dispatchEvent(new window.Event('scroll'));
};

const scrollByMock = function scrollByMock(left, top) { scrollMock(window.screenX + left, window.screenY + top); };

const resizeMock = (width, height) => {
  Object.defineProperties(document.body, {
    scrollHeight: { value: 1000, writable: false },
    scrollWidth: { value: 1000, writable: false },
  });
  Object.assign(window, {
    innerWidth: width,
    innerHeight: height,
    outerWidth: width,
    outerHeight: height,
  }).dispatchEvent(new window.Event('resize'));
};

const scrollIntoViewMock = function scrollIntoViewMock() {
  const [left, top] = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  window.scrollTo(left, top);
};

const getBoundingClientRectMock = function getBoundingClientRectMock() {
  let offsetParent = this;
  const result = new DOMRect(0, 0, this.offsetWidth, this.offsetHeight);
  while (offsetParent) {
    result.x += offsetParent.offsetX;
    result.y += offsetParent.offsetY;
    offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent;
  }
  return result;
};

function mockGlobal(key, value) {
  mockedGlobals[key] = global[key]; // this is just to be able to reset the mocks after the tests
  global[key] = value;
}

beforeAll(async () => {
  mockGlobal('scroll', scrollMock);
  mockGlobal('scrollTo', scrollMock);
  mockGlobal('scrollBy', scrollByMock);
  mockGlobal('resizeTo', resizeMock);

  Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'scrollIntoView', { value: scrollIntoViewMock, writable: false });
  Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'getBoundingClientRect', { value: getBoundingClientRectMock, writable: false });
  Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth', { value: 250, writable: false });
  Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetHeight', { value: 250, writable: false });
  
});
```

The above ensures that, after a programmatic scroll takes place, the appropriate `ScrollEvent` will be published, and the `window` properties are updated accordingly.

**2. Mocks that setup a basic layout for a collection of siblings**

```
export function getPosition(element) {
  return element?.getClientRects()[0];
}

export function scrollToElement(element, [extraX = 0, extraY = 0]) {
  const { x, y } = getPosition(element);
  window.scrollTo(x + extraX, y + extraY);
}

export const layoutTypes = {
  column: 'column',
  row: 'row',
};

function* getLayoutBoxIterator(type, { defaultElementSize }) {
  const [width, height] = defaultElementSize;
  let offset = 0;
  while (true) {
    let left = 0;
    let top = 0;
    if (type === layoutTypes.column) {
      top += offset;
      offset += height;
    } else if (type === layoutTypes.row) {
      left += offset;
      offset += width;
    }
    yield new DOMRect(left, top, width, height);
  }
}

function getLayoutProps(element, layoutBox) {
  return {
    offsetX: layoutBox.x,
    offsetY: layoutBox.y,
    offsetWidth: layoutBox.width,
    offsetHeight: layoutBox.height,
    scrollWidth: layoutBox.width,
    scrollHeight: layoutBox.height,
  };
}

function defineReadonlyProperties(child, props) {
  let readonlyProps = Object.entries(props).reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => {
    accumulator[key] = {
      value,
      writable: false,
    }; return accumulator;
  }, {});
  Object.defineProperties(child, readonlyProps);
}

export function mockLayout(parent, type, options = { defaultElementSize: [250, 250] }) {
  const layoutBoxIterator = getLayoutBoxIterator(type, options);
  const parentLayoutBox = new DOMRect(parent.offsetX, parent.offsetY, parent.offsetWidth, parent.offsetHeight);
  let maxBottom = 0;
  let maxRight = 0;
  Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children).forEach((child) => {
    let layoutBox = layoutBoxIterator.next().value;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
    defineReadonlyProperties(child, getLayoutProps(child, layoutBox));
    maxBottom = Math.max(maxBottom, layoutBox.bottom);
    maxRight = Math.max(maxRight, layoutBox.right);
  });
  parentLayoutBox.width = Math.max(parentLayoutBox.width, maxRight);
  parentLayoutBox.height = Math.max(parentLayoutBox.height, maxBottom);
  defineReadonlyProperties(parent, getLayoutProps(parent, parentLayoutBox));
}
```

With those two in place, I would write my tests like this:

```
// given
mockLayout(/* put the common, direct parent of the siblings here */, layoutTypes.column);

// when
Simulate.click(document.querySelector('#nextStepButton')); // trigger the event that causes programmatic scroll
const scrolledElementPosition = ...; // get offsetX of the component that was scrolled programmatically

// then
expect(window.scrollX).toEqual(scrolledElementPosition.x); // verify that the programmatically scrolled element is now at the top of the page, or some other desired outcome
```

The idea here is that you give all siblings at a given level sensible, uniform widths and heights, as if they were rendered as a column / row, thus imposing a simple layout structure that the `table` component will 'see' when calculating which children to show / hide.

Note that in your scenario, the common parent of the sibling elements might not be the root HTML element rendered by `table`, but some element nested inside. Check the generated HTML to see how to best obtain a handle.

Your use case is a little different, in that you're triggering the event yourself, rather than having it bound to a specific action (a button click, for instance). Therefore, you might not need the first part in its entirety.